# Segfault in pluginlib-tutorial whenever adding Plugins-Description-File between <export> tags

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Have anyone experienced a weird behavior below when working with pluginlib? Could you please help me understand the problem?

I trying to work with pluginlib by following the [wiki-tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib/Tutorials/Writing%20and%20Using%20a%20Simple%20Plugin). By installing pluginlib-tutorials using `sudo apt install ros-kinematic-pluginlib-tutorials`, the main node works fine and normal.

But to build the same package from source, the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` keep appearing everytime adding `<pluginlib_tutorials_ plugin="${prefix}/polygon_plugins.xml" />` in the `package.xml` file.

I can successfully initialize the `pluginlib::ClassLoader` object, but without "Plugin Description File" in the `package.xml`, I can not create plugin-instances.

My workspace setting:

```
test_ws/
└── src
    ├── pluginlib_tutorials_
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── include
    │   │   └── pluginlib_tutorials_
    │   │       ├── polygon_base.h
    │   │       └── polygon_plugins.h
    │   ├── package.xml
    │   ├── polygon_plugins.xml
    │   └── src
    │       ├── polygon_loader.cpp
    │       └── polygon_plugins.cpp
```

package.xml:

```
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>pluginlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>pluginlib</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <export>
    <pluginlib_tutorials_ plugin="${prefix}/polygon_plugins.xml" /> 
  </export>
```

Could anyone please help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352954/segfault-in-pluginlib-tutorial-whenever-adding-plugins-description-file-between-%3Cexport%3E-tags/) by [DangTran](https://answers.ros.org/users/53085/dangtran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2020-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally understand the problem and fixed it successfully: The main reason is `ros::package::xxx()` compatible with `boost-1.58` (installed by `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`) while I was using `boost-1.70`(from source) [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/249017/rospack-segmentation-fault/). Return everything back to `boost-1.58`, everything's fine.

---

Originally posted by [DangTran](https://answers.ros.org/users/53085/dangtran/) with karma: 66 on 2020-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0